# What is the significance of the "date designation expires" on a temporary airman certificate?

Tags: faa-regulations, pilots, pilot-certification, student-pilot

I recently received my temporary airman certificate and it says that it expires in 120 days. However, there is a section that says "date designation expires". The date under "date designation expires" is not 120 days. So my question is, does it expire 120 days after the date of issuance or on the date under "date designation expires"? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "date designation expires"

**Assuming your temporary certificate is issued in the United States**.

Is the date that the Designated Examiner's designation expires (assuming it was a "Designated Examiner" who issued the temporary certificate).

A Designated examiner's authority has to be periodically renewed.

This is not the date your temporary certificate expires, which is 120 days from issuance.

Answer (score 0):

*This answer assumes you are in the United States.*

I can't find one of my temporary certificates sitting around at this moment, but I'm 97.2% sure that `Date Designation Expires` is the date that the examiner or inspector who gave you the certificate's designation expires.

I can **100% guarantee you that your temporary certificate expires 120 days after the date of issuance**, unless it is otherwise renewed, superseded, or revoked as stated in the limitations on the certificate itself.